# Is Coefficient of viscosity frame dependent? Why/Why not?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, reference-frames, fluid-statics, flow, viscosity

Is Coefficient of viscosity frame dependent? Why/Why not?

Comment: Hint: Is it a scalar or a vector?

Comment: What do you think? What physics concept are you specifically struggling with?

Comment: I think it's independent of frame because it's a nature of a particular fluid... But I want to confirm if it's frame dependent or independent.....

Answer (score 0):

The *viscosity could potentially be directionally dependent* but in most common systems it can be assumed with good accuracy to be approximately isotropic.

A body in strength of materials is assumed to act like a spring while common **fluids** in fluid mechanics are characterised by **energy dissipation**. A fluid basically acts like a huge viscous dampener where the **viscosity** is the **characteristic damping coefficient of the fluid**. [**In theory this dissipation could be anisotropic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newtonian_fluid#For_anisotropic_fluids) (just like the stiffness tensor in strength of materials) but the commonly used formulation of the Navier-Stokes equations found in textbooks make use of **isotropic Newtonian fluids**. There are **exotic substances** such as [*para-azoxyanisol*](https://www.nature.com/articles/158027b0) that have a **flow-induced anisotropic viscosity** (a different viscosity in flow direction, in the direction of the velocity gradient and perpendicular to the other two) or [*paramagnetic colloids*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/article/turbulent-flow-of-a-fluid-with-anisotropic-viscosity/B92448475FA5F23B7558820B4CBD88E4) under an **external magnetic field**. So in those applications your viscosity would change with orientation to the main flow or magnetic field. Furthermore **eddy viscosity** of turbulence models in rotating flows is highly anisotropic.